# Replacing the XML node using XSLT is working only at root level

Tags: xslt

I am working on a functionality where I am supposed to replace the existing XML nodes to a different one. I have written the code to achieve the same. However it is only replacing the root node and not the child. If you notice the root node SpecExportViewModel getting replaced with the node Spec. However the child nodes are returned as it is without transforming. For example the node OpeningsExportViewModel is not getting replaced with the node DRSCHEDS as per the XSLT code. Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Please find my XML and XSLT file below.

```html
<SpecExportViewModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  -
  <Openings>
    -
    <OpeningsExportViewModel>
      <SpecId>1945</SpecId>
      <MarkNumber>UNI</MarkNumber>
      <DoorNumber>UNI</DoorNumber>
      <AreaNumber />
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <OutSideLocation />
      <InsideLocation />
      <HardwareSetNumber>HOSASET</HardwareSetNumber>
      <Hand>AS</Hand>
      <ActiveDegree />
      <InActiveDegree />
      <FrameType>UNK</FrameType>
      <DoorType>UNK</DoorType>
      <Remarks />
      <Scratch />
      <Rating>20PP</Rating>
      <Height>84</Height>
      <Width>41</Width>
      <Thickness>1.75</Thickness>
      <Mode />
      <ActiveleafWidth />
      <ActiveLeafHeight />
      <InactiveLeafWidth />
      <InactiveLeafHeight />
      <Transom>NON</Transom>
      <TransomHeight />
      <TransombarFacedim />
      <FrameConfig>3SIDED</FrameConfig>
      <TempRise>False</TempRise>
      <LeadLined>False</LeadLined>
      <StormLabel />
      <StcRating />
      <ArchDrElev />
      <ArchFrElev />
      <ArchHeadDetail />
      <ArchJambDetail />
      <ArchSillDetail />
      <Tags />
      <Walltype>VERIFY</Walltype>
      <WallThick>4.875</WallThick>
      <KeyGrp />
      <OsFloorFin />
      <InFloorFin />
      <OurSillDetail />
      <Accessories />
      <Frameset />
      <Doorset />
      <ExporteDhDwe />
      <SillDwg />
      <Exterior />
      <Modifier />
      <AutoHdg />
    </OpeningsExportViewModel>
  </Openings>
</SpecExportViewModel>
```

XSLT File:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="SpecExportViewModel">
    <Spec>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </Spec>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[@*]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="SpecExportViewModel/OpeningsExportViewModel">
    <DRSCHEDS>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
    </DRSCHEDS>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SpecExportViewModel/OpeningsExportViewModel/Openings">
    <DRSCHED>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
    </DRSCHED>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours XPaths at template matches are wrong.
`SpecExportViewModel/OpeningsExportViewModel`, and
`SpecExportViewModel/OpeningsExportViewModel/Openings`

`Openings` is the parent of `OpeningsExportViewModel` in your input(not a child).

If it is just the element names you wanted to change(and keep attributes and other unspecified nodes same), go with this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="SpecExportViewModel">
    <Spec>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </Spec>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="SpecExportViewModel/Openings">
    <DRSCHEDS>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </DRSCHEDS>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="SpecExportViewModel/Openings/OpeningsExportViewModel">
    <DRSCHED>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </DRSCHED>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Lingamurthy. My bad.